2 screens and 1 turn black on one half
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my PC and am using two monitors: an ultrawide with a 1440p resolution and a standard FHD display, however the ultrawide monitor's screen turns black on one half. I am using an RTX 3060 Ti graphics card.


Are you using X.org or Wayland?
